# SQL Query - Distinct or Unique?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique, distinct

New to SQL and have a query pulling some data with a number of joins across a number of tables.

Sample Data:

```
PERSON_NAME FUNCTION_NAME  FUNCTION_ID  FUNCTION_GROUP

Bob         View Result    1            Editor
Bob         Edit Result    4            Editor
Bob         Delete Result  3            Editor
Bob         Email Result   8            Editor
Mary        Print Letter   45           Admin
Mary        Grant Access   37           Admin
```

Functions have IDs, and function_groups have numerous functions.  I want to query the data so instead of how it appears similar to the example above, it would look like:

```
PERSON_NAME FUNCTION_NAME                             FUNCTION_ID     FUNCTION_GROUP

Bob         View Result,Edit Result, Delete Result   1,4,3,8          Editor
Mary        Print Letter,Grant Access                 45,37           Admin
```

"Bob belongs to Editor, editor has the following functions" as one result, rather than the initial example, where multiple line after line is returned.

Am I correct in thinking the unique or distinct keywords can help me?
Thanks!

EDIT: Now with code

```
select staff_member.person_name, function.function_name,staff_group_function.function_id, staff_group.function_group_name
 from staff_member
 inner join staff_group
 on staff_group.staff_group_id=staff_group_member.staff_group_id
 inner join staff_group_function
 on staff_group_function.staff_group_id=staff_group_member.staff_group_id
 inner join function
 on function.function_id=staff_group_function.function_group_name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. What you need is [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) if you have Oracle 11g2. This could be your query:

```
SELECT person_name,
       LISTAGG(function_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) function_name,
       LISTAGG(function_id,   ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) function_id,
       function_group
FROM my_table
GROUP BY person_name, function_group
```

alternatively (following your latest comment):

```
SELECT person_name,
       LISTAGG(function_name,  ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) function_name,
       LISTAGG(function_id,    ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) function_id,
       LISTAGG(function_group, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) function_group
FROM my_table
GROUP BY person_name
```

For any version prior to 11g2, this interesting article holds the solution for you:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Comment: Or to implement this behavior in about 10 minutes in any turing complete programming language

Comment: Using 10G.  Useful link! wmsys.concat works. :)  However, I actually just want one instance of Bob, forget about the function name listing for the moment.  How can I make it only list Bob/Mary once as a member of Editor/Admin?

Comment: @GrumP: I'm guessing, then, I misinterpreted your goal. Try grouping only by `person_name` and aggregating `function_group` the same way as the other fields...

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  No you did not misinterpret my goal, I did!  The advice is correct for what I *thought* I needed.  Turns out what I needed was much simpler.  I'm sure I will use wmsys.concat at a later stage I imagine! :)

Comment: I added a group by at the end (code now in Orig Post) but it gives "not a GROUP BY expression"?

Comment: @GrumP: Please ask a new question for that. It will be difficult for future visitors to follow how this question has evolved...

Answer (score 2):

`UNIQUE` and `DISTINCT` have nothing to do with grouping and aggregating your results. You have to `GROUP BY` `PERSON_NAME` and `FUNCTION_GROUP` and then apply your own [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) to group the remaining results.

This [article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) tells you exactly how to concatenate with commas strings via an aggregate function in Oracle using `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 1):

In `10g` it works like below

```
with tab as (
 select 'Bob' PERSON_NAME,'View Result' FUNCTION_NAME,'1' FUNCTION_ID,'Editor' FUNCTION_GROUP      from dual
union all
select 'Bob' PERSON_NAME,'Edit Result' FUNCTION_NAME,'4' FUNCTION_ID,'Editor' FUNCTION_GROUP from    dual
union all
select 'Bob' PERSON_NAME ,'Delete Result'FUNCTION_NAME,'3' FUNCTION_ID,'Editor' FUNCTION_GROUP from dual
union all
select 'Bob' PERSON_NAME,'Email Result' FUNCTION_NAME,'8' FUNCTION_ID,'Editor' FUNCTION_GROUP from dual
union all
select 'Mary' PERSON_NAME,'Print Letter' FUNCTION_NAME,'45' FUNCTION_ID,'Admin' FUNCTION_GROUP from dual
union all
select 'Mary' PERSON_NAME , 'Grant Access' FUNCTION_NAME ,'37' FUNCTION_ID,'Admin' FUNCTION_GROUP from dual
 )
select person_name
      ,wm_concat(function_name) function_name
      ,wm_concat(function_id) function_id
      ,function_group
 from tab
 group by person_name,function_group
```

**output**
[image: output]

Comment: Hi Gaurav, this is exactly what I want.  I tried changing my code to implement this logic, but not getting it right.  With the sample sql in my original question, can you advise how I can change to produce the output you have?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's in my original post.

Comment: @Philleh:I mean how you have used `wm_concat` in your query ?,i can see a query but what have you tried to get desired result with comma seperated group set